# Jquery Post Not Calling Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, authentication, jquery-post

Good morning!

I have a user login page "/Account/Login.aspx" which uses a custom 
I've included an  tag for the user to reset their password - `<a href="javascript:ConfirmPasswordChange();">Forgot Password?</a>`

My post doesn't call my page "/Account/LoginMethods.aspx" (No breakpoint firing), but instead returns the result as the entire content of the user login page "/Account/Login.aspx" html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function ConfirmPasswordChange() {
                $("#ConfiormPasswordReset").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    autoResize: true,
                    title: "Reset Password",
                    draggable: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Cancel': function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        'Continue': function () {
                            SendNewPassword();
                        }
                    }
                }).dialog("open");
                $('#ConfiormPasswordReset').focus();
            }

            function SendNewPassword() {
                $.post("/Account/LoginMethods.aspx", { UserEmail: $("#UserName").val() },
                    function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    });
                $('#ConfiormPasswordReset').dialog("close");
            }
    </script>
```

Any Idea of the possible problem?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting redirected server-side back to `Login.aspx`

Comment: How do You read the UserEmail variable on the server side ?

Comment: It doesn't get to the .cs page, so it makes no difference how it is read

Comment: @Nick - Thank you, I was being stupid and forgot to allow my LoginMethods page access without credentials, so it was being redirected. Should I delete the question or answer it myself?

Comment: I added one below with a bit more context on the AJAX side, hope this helps others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your `LoginMethods.aspx` page is rejecting the request, redirecting back to `Login.aspx` because you're lacking credentials.  When you make an AJAX request, XmlHttpRequest **transparently** follows redirects, so it'll spit out whatever it finally ended up being redirected to.